# get information from 2 table in sqlite from 2 different fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 2 tables : book and user ,now I need to make another table but it should get some fields from book and some from user ,separately I can ,but when I go to another fragment to get other fields from book table the username ,which I save it to a string, returns null

```
   08-04 10:47:27.319 4004-4004/com.example.pars.amanatdari I/bookName: args : Bundle[{status=null, userName=jack, bookName=null}]
08-04 10:47:30.139 4004-4004/com.example.pars.amanatdari I/bookName: args : Bundle[{status=available, userName=null, bookName=نون والقلم}]
```

what should I do exactly?I dont know even what to search

send data from fragment :

```
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String username = args.getString("userName");
```

and get data :

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String bookName = bundle.getString("bookName");
            String bookStatus = bundle.getString("status");
            String bookUser = bundle.getString("userName");

            borrowFragment borrowFragment = new borrowFragment();
            Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
            args2.putString("bookName", bookName);
            args2.putString("status", bookStatus);
            args2.putString("userName", bookUser);
            Log.i("bookName", "args : " + args2);
            borrowFragment.setArguments(args2);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frg_container, borrowFragment, "tag").commit();
```

Comment: so basically you take few values from book fragment and then navigate to user fragment and then navigate to third fragment and the values that you take from book fragment are null right ? First of all , I would recommend you to migrate to navigation Components and use safe args to transfer values from one fragment to another . In this case , for now, you can simply use a data class and a shared viewModel between the three classes . Reply while confirming the above question that I have asked to get a more valid answer

Comment: yeah you almost right but first i get some value from user table then i go to another fragment to choose a book when i return back the username becomes null

Comment: Is the issue solved ?

Comment: yes you saved me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is bound to happen , since the bundle gets null or overwritten after your visit to the book fragment .So what can be done is you can get the values from user fragment and pass the value to book fragment and then take both the values and go to the next fragment . You have to carry the data with you all the while